# proxy_pass does not work properly

Tags: nginx, proxy, gunicorn, converse.js

I need to resolve some Cross Domain Policy issues for our team's project setup (Converse.js, 
XMPP, BOSH, ...) by setting up a nginx reverse proxy configuration.

I want to archieve exactly these bindings:

- nginx to local gunicorn HTTP server 
  `http://my.nginx.server.com/` should proxy `http://localhost:8000/`
- nginx to remote HTTP-server for BOSH
  `http://my.nginx.server.com/http-bind` should proxy `http://some.very.remote.server:5280/http-bind`

Currently, only the first binding works. The second one doesn't. nginx delivers every request to the local gunicorn HTTP server and not to the remote server.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
...
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # Reverse proxy for remote HTTP server
    location ~ ^/http-bind/ {
        proxy_pass http://some.very.remote.server:5280;
    }

    # Reverse proxy for local gunicorn HTTP server
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http://$server_name http://$server_name:8000;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this working configuration:

```
        location /http-bind {
            proxy_pass http://sapbot.mo.sap.corp:5280/http-bind;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_buffering off;
            tcp_nodelay on;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect http://$server_name http://$server_name:8000;
        }
```